# Deploy to multiple heroku instances using a ruby script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, deployment, capistrano

I have three heroku apps with same code-base, one points to admin interface, one user interface and last to staging application for testing.if i do a single change then i have to deploy to all three instances one by one that is a very tedious task, i need a help in writing a script which deploy to all three instances at once. i saw this post which says that `Capistrano` can't be used for this.

[Deploying on Heroku with Capistrano?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13007282/deploying-on-heroku-with-capistrano)

Comment: If you need interactive help, you better go to remote-pairing sites (codementor, airpair or similar)

Comment: What is exactly your problem in doing this? You can use --app option on heroku commands to specify the application

Comment: @SergioTulentsev not exactly there is will be heroku command to run  the migrations as well.

Comment: @SachinSingh: so, 4 lines?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev now i am writing a ruby gem for that, i will show you after few days, i mean to say its just not about pushing the code.

Comment: @SachinSingh: now that's the great attitude! :)

Answer (score 0):

As per my opinion this could be the answer

```
   git push heroku master -a app_a
   heroku run rake db:migrate -a app_a

   git push heroku master -a app_b
   heroku run rake db:migrate -a app_b

   git push heroku master -a app_c
   heroku run rake db:migrate -a app_c
```

if anything i am missing please add it to this answer.

I am writing a ruby gem for it, and after that i will update my answer.

Comment: This won't work since `-a` does something very different in git.