# deploy database.yml with Capistrano 3 in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, capistrano, capistrano3

I have a Rails 4 app that connects to a second, external database. So I added the database credentials to my `database.yml` file and excluded it from version control in `git`. I need to deploy it when I `push` to `Heroku` using `Capistrano`.

I found some questions raised for this task, but they don't work for me and they were answered prior to the release of `Capistrano 3`.

I set up `capistrano` by adding:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.1.1'
end
```

and

running `bundle install` then `bundle exec cap install` as it says in the install instructions.

I created a new folder in my app and copied the `database.yml` file there: `myApp/shared/config/database.yml` (not sure if this was necessary)

Finally, I created the following task in `deply.rb`:

```
after "deploy:update_code","deploy:config_symlink"

namespace :deploy do

  task :config_symlink do
    run "cp #{shared_path}/shared/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
  end
end
```

This didn't work and threw an error when pushed to `Heroku`:

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:248:in `resolve_symbol_connection': 'pg_development' database is not configured. Available: ["production"] (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
```

I tried putting this task in the `production.rb` file as well as adding `set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}` to the `development.rb` file.

Can someone help me get the `database.yml` file into production on `Heroku`?

Comment: As fas as I'm concerned, you cannot deploy to heroku using capistrano. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13007282/deploying-on-heroku-with-capistrano